# VOIP Push delegates does not called when app is terminated and phone is locked

Tags: ios, objective-c, voip, callkit, pushkit

I am working over VOIP application, i received voip push when app is in foreground or background as well but when app is terminated or force quit
and the iPhone went to Lock mode… device get voip push (i checked in device console)

```
Received message for enabled topic 'com.kipl.app.voip' with payload '{
    aps =     {
        alert = "Misscall from +91 9782260101";
        "content-available" = 1;
        sound = default;
    };
    "message_data" =     {
        UUID = "E740A875-65B2-4E4C-AF3C-3B886AA040F3";
        handle = 919782260101;
        hasVideo = 0;
        image = "201702/589c6c27febed30d03c32f54.jpg";
        message = "Misscall from +91 9782260101";
        phone = "+91 9782260101";
        pushType = miscall;
        username = "";
    };
}' onInterface: NonCellular  for device token: NO  with priority (null)
Mar  4 12:52:14 iPhone apsd(PersistentConnection)[86] <Notice>: 2017-03-04 12:52:14 +0530 apsd[86]: <APSMessageStore: 0x10035adb0> asked to store incoming message <APSIncomingMessage: 0x1003a1f00> with guid B0C02302-772D-423B-A525-A0115F98DA29 environment <APSEnvironment: 0x10030f610: production>
Mar  4 12:52:14 iPhone apsd(PersistentConnection)[86] <Notice>: 2017-03-04 12:52:14 +0530 apsd[86]: <APSCourier: 0x100311180>: Calling into AWD for PushReceived
Mar  4 12:52:14 iPhone apsd(PersistentConnection)[86] <Notice>: 2017-03-04 12:52:14 +0530 apsd[86]: <APSCourier: 0x100311180>: AWD for PushReceived finished
Mar  4 12:52:14 iPhone apsd(PersistentConnection)[86] <Notice>: 2017-03-04 12:52:14 +0530 apsd[86]: <APSCourier: 0x100311180>: Stream processing: complete no, invalid no, length parsed 0, parameters (null)
Mar  4 12:52:14 iPhone apsd(PersistentConnection)[86] <Notice>: 2017-03-04 12:52:14 +0530 apsd[86]: APSMessageStore - New message record [<APSIncomingMessageRecord 0x1004d7540 [0x1ac0d6bb8]>{}] has ID [1400].
Mar  4 12:52:14 iPhone apsd(PersistentConnection)[86] <Notice>: 2017-03-04 12:52:14 +0530 apsd[86]: <APSMessageStore: 0x10035adb0> calling completion block for incoming message B0C02302-772D-423B-A525-A0115F98DA29
Mar  4 12:52:14 iPhone apsd(PersistentConnection)[86] <Notice>: 2017-03-04 12:52:14 +0530 apsd[86]: <APSCourier: 0x100311180>: Sending acknowledgement message with response 0 and messageId <04000000> (4)
Mar  4 12:52:14 iPhone apsd(PersistentConnection)[86] <Notice>: 2017-03-04 12:52:14 +0530 apsd[86]: <APSCourier: 0x100311180> Noting push - using last lq 0 and rat (null)  (instead of -2, kCTRegistrationRadioAccessTechnologyUnknown)
Mar  4 12:52:14 iPhone apsd(PersistentConnection)[86] <Notice>: 2017-03-04 12:52:14 +0530 apsd[86]: <APSDecayTimer: 0x1004127f0>:APSNetworkMonitor decaying cost (381 - 6) = 375 for 24.425812 seconds
Mar  4 12:52:14 iPhone apsd(PersistentConnection)[86] <Notice>: 2017-03-04 12:52:14 +0530 apsd[86]: <APSDecayTimer: 0x1004127f0>:APSNetworkMonitor addCost: 166 - _currentCost is now 541
Mar  4 12:52:14 iPhone apsd(PersistentConnection)[86] <Notice>: 2017-03-04 12:52:14 +0530 apsd[86]: <APSCourier: 0x100311180> _notifyForIncomingMessage <APSIncomingMessage: 0x1003a1f00> with guid B0C02302-772D-423B-A525-A0115F98DA29
Mar  4 12:52:14 iPhone apsd(PersistentConnection)[86] <Notice>: 2017-03-04 12:52:14 +0530 apsd[86]: Dispatching high priority message: <OS_xpc_dictionary: <dictionary: 0x1003ed2a0> { count = 2, transaction: 0, voucher = 0x0, contents =
    "message" => <dictionary: 0x10038a050> { count = 1, transaction: 0, voucher = 0x0, contents =
        "ECF19A18-7AA6-4141-B4DC-A2E5123B2B5C" => <data: 0x1003a8360>: { length = 16384 bytes, contents = 0x62706c6973743135137e020000000000801200000000d87f... }
    }
    "message-type" => <int64: 0x10035c950>: 30
}>
```

Also `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` called but **pushkit** delegate does not call. Also i am using call kit for incoming calls.

1) When app in forground ... push work

2) App remove from background and lock the phone ... push receive  in device but pushkit delegate not call .. problem that

Could anyone please suggest, how do I overcome this issue?

Answer (score -1):

You can also refer whole pushkit process step by step.

Swift and Objective C code is also there.

https://github.com/hasyapanchasara/PushKit_SilentPushNotification

**Please refer below code for pushkit delegate in AppDelegate.**

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface AppDelegate ()

@end

@implementation AppDelegate


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {


    pushRegistry = [[PKPushRegistry alloc] initWithQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
    pushRegistry.delegate = self;
    pushRegistry.desiredPushTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:PKPushTypeVoIP];

    return YES;
}

#define PushKit Delegate Methods

- (void)pushRegistry:(PKPushRegistry *)registry didUpdatePushCredentials:(PKPushCredentials *)credentials forType:(NSString *)type{
    if([credentials.token length] == 0) {
        NSLog(@"voip token NULL");
        return;
    }

    NSLog(@"PushCredentials: %@", credentials.token);
}

- (void)pushRegistry:(PKPushRegistry *)registry didReceiveIncomingPushWithPayload:(PKPushPayload *)payload forType:(NSString *)type
{
    NSLog(@"didReceiveIncomingPushWithPayload");
}

- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}

@end
```

Hope this will help you.

All the best.

**To debug pudhkit delegate in terminated state.**

Put debug pointer on delegate methods, Go to edit scheme, select run option then Launch -> Wait for executable to be launched. Send push kit payload from back end, once you get payload on device, it will automatically invoke and debug pointer will invoke at delegate methods.

[image]

Comment: i am doing same for pushkit even push is working when app is in foreground or background, as i mentioned in my question.

Comment: If pushkit delegate gets called in foreground and background then it must work in terminated state. Try scheduling local notification based on payload you receive. You can also debug app when app is in terminated state.

Comment: – Hasya  are you check ?

Comment: that is the problem i did not receive payload in terminated state whereas device received as i checked in device log. didReceiveIncomingPushWithPayload does not invoke so that i can get the payload to schedule local notification and i am using call kit for handling incoming calls.

Comment: Make demo code only with pushkit and give google drive URL in your question, So anyone can download and give you solution.

Comment: @Hasya now push is working, i checked device crash log in app terminated state, my application was crashing in port sip service class in video codec  setting and voip push will not receive in case of app crash.

Comment: 'didReceiveIncomingPushWithPayload' not get called when receive voip. (Iam using quickblox. 'didReceiveNewSession' delegate methods triggering when received new calll)